# Jqgrid how to Reset or Set searchOperator in the filterToolbar

Tags: jquery

The grid works great, I use the filtertoolbar in each column. 'Eq' is the default value.
The problem is when I change the searchOperator and then after clear the whole grid, the searchOperator does't back to the initial state.

In my case I just have two searchOperators values 'eq' and 'cn', (default 'eq').

After change to 'cn' the search is ok, but after reset the grid, the searchOperator still in 'cn', I need the starting value 'eq'.

For reset the grid I use the refresh button in the navbar, and use these others, but nothing happen:

```
var sgrid = jQuery("#lista_productos")[0];sgrid.clearToolbar();
```

OR

```
$('#lista_productos').clearForm();
```

Thank for your help

Alf

I found this with firebug

```
<td class="ui-search-oper" colindex="2">
     <a class="soptclass" colname="Mfr" soper="cn" style="padding-right: 0.5em;" title="Click to select search operation.">~</a>
</td>
```

I need to change the value of soper and the '~' value, but I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Well after some investigations in Jquery, I found the answer. Just put in LoadComplete, and it work ok.

```
$("a.soptclass[colname='FieldName']").attr("soper","eq");
$("a.soptclass[colname='FieldName']").text("==");
```

Have a good day.